# SonarQube Warning for null reference

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have 2 pieces of code where the core logic is same but SonarQube behaves different and gives me a warning:

First see the no warning snip:

[image: NO-WARNING]

Now the warning thrown:

[image: Warning]

Why am I seeing the warning at one place and not other. ALso, How Can I overcome this warning.

I have already tried:

```
foreach (JObject item in jArray)
{
   if(item != null)
   {
      clusterIds.Add(item.GetValue("value").ToString());
}}
```

or checking if `item.values != null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent .NET versions, `.ToString()` is declared as `string? ToString()`, so it could return null.

The difference you're seeing is because [the string concatenation operator `+=`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator#string-concatenation) allows a null string to be concatenated to a non-null string (it does nothing), but your `clusterIds` is declared as a list that cannot contain nulls, so you get the warning that you're seeing.

To be clear, this is OK:

```
string x = "x";
x += null;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

And this will give you a warning:

```
List<string> y = new List<string>();
y.Add(null);  // Not OK
```

You can suppress the warning by adding a `null-forgiving` operator:

```
clusterIds.Add(item.GetValue("value").ToString()!);
```

Comment: Thanks For your response, however "clusterIds.Add(item.GetValue("value").ToString()!);" still gives me the warning. Not sure if we can use this operator with list.

Comment: You can use that operator like that, I've used it many times. Does `clusterIds.Add(item.GetValue("value")!.ToString()!);` work?

Comment: clusterIds.Add(item.GetValue("value")!.ToString());  this worked. Thanks for your help :)